# Mysql Variable With Multiple Values

Tags: mysql

The following works as expected when there is a single value stored in a variable:

```
Set @var = 121;
select * from table where id = @var;
```

How can I set variable with multiple value and then use it in a query. I have tried this but it doesn't work:

```
set @var = (
  117,120,121,122,143,151,175,233,387,189,118,119,339,357,500,501,493,425,307,191,
  117,120,121,122,143,151,175,233,387,189,118,119,339,357,500,501,493,425,307,191,
  117,120,121,122,143,151,175,233,387,189,118,119,339,357,500,501,493,425,307,191
)
select * from table where id = @var;
```

Answer (score 5):

```
set @var = '
  117,120,121,122,143,151,175,233,387,189,118,119,339,357,500,501,493,425,307,191,
  117,120,121,122,143,151,175,233,387,189,118,119,339,357,500,501,493,425,307,191,
  117,120,121,122,143,151,175,233,387,189,118,119,339,357,500,501,493,425,307,191'

SELECT * FROM table WHERE FIND_IN_SET(id,@var);
```

Thanks buddy

Answer (score 1):

You can to this by set the `@var` as comma separated string and use like to get the data. This is not perfect but workable and you have to take care about the value in `@var`. There should n't be any invalid char like `space`

```
Mysql> set @var = '117,120,121,122,143,151,175,233,387,189,118,119,339,357,500,501,493,425,307,191,117,120,121,122,143,151,175,233,12';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

Hitesh> select * from test where ((@var like concat(id,',%')) or  (@var like concat('%,',id)) or (@var like concat('%,',id,',%')) or  (@var like id));
+----+------+-------+
| ID | NAME | VALUE |
+----+------+-------+
| 12 | Nee  |  NULL |
+----+------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

You can also use `LOCATE` function instead of `like`. MySQL LOCATE() returns the position of the first occurrence of a string within a string. Both of these strings are passed as arguments. An optional argument may be used to specify from which position of the string (i.e. string to be searched) searching will start. If this position is not mentioned, searching starts from the beginning.

syntax `LOCATE(substr,str)`

```
mysql> SELECT LOCATE('st','myteststring'); 
+-----------------------------+
| LOCATE('st','myteststring') |
+-----------------------------+
|                           5 | 
+-----------------------------+
```

`FIND_IN_SET()` is perfect one for your case. It `must have strin`g values as `comma separated`.

Answer (score -1):

You should use IN

```
select * from table where id IN ( @var );
```

Comment: This raises an "ERROR 1241 (21000): Operand should contain 1 column(s)".